# Django framework: unable to load 'services' page

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm working on a Django project.

I think there is some problem with the use of '**services**' word in the django project. Please see if you can find some corrections required in the project.

The project name is **Hello**. There is one additional app '**home**'.

When I navigate to the **index, contact, or about** page, all of them are working (loading) as expected.

I'm using following list item (in *base.html*) to navigate to the '**services**' page:

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/services">Ice Cream</a></li>
```

But **services** page is not loading. If I change '**services**' to '**service**' everywhere, then it **works** as usual. It's giving the following error:

[image]

Following are some of the file contents:

> Hello->urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

admin.site.site_header = "Harry Ice Cream Admin"
admin.site.site_title = "Harry Ice Cream Admin Portal"
admin.site.index_title = "Welcome to Harry Ice Creams!"

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls')),
]
```

> home->urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('services', views.services, name='services'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

> home->views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    context = {
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html',context)
    #return HttpResponse("This is homepage")

def about(request):
    context = {
    }
    return render(request, 'about.html',context)

def services(request):
    context = {
    }
    return render(request, 'services.html',context)

def contact(request):
    context = {
    }
    return render(request, 'contact.html',context)
```

> templates->index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Home {% endblock title %}

{% block body %}
This is body content of index page.
{% endblock body %}
```

> templates->about.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} About {% endblock title %}

{% block body %}
This is body content of about page.
{% endblock body %}
```

> templates->services.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} About {% endblock title %}

{% block body %}
This is body content of services page.
{% endblock body %}
```

> templates->contact.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} About {% endblock title %}

{% block body %}
This is body content of contactpage.
{% endblock body %}
```

> templates->base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock title %} | Harry IceCreams</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Harry Ice Creams</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/services" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Services
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/services">Ice Cream</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Softy</a></li>
                  <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Family Pack</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    {% block body %} {% endblock body%}
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: error shows it can't find  `services/`, not `services` - you have to add `/` at the ends of url in  `path('services/', ...)`. You may need it in other `path()` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `http:127.0.0.1:8000/services`

NOT THIS          `http:127.0.0.1:8000/services/`

delete the last of the url **/**

if you want this to work `http:127.0.0.1:8000/services/` you need to edit the following in urls.py file.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('services/', views.services, name='services'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

As you can see, I put **/** at the end of the "servies" url path.

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/services">Ice Cream</a></li>
```

For this, do as follows.

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'services' %}">Ice Cream</a></li>
```

this {% url '**services**' %} come from **name** of the your **services** **url** **path**.

Comment: '/' at the end of 'http:127.0.0.1:8000/services/' is getting added automatically after I click enter with 'http:127.0.0.1:8000/services'. Don't know why. (Please see if you can explain this) This is not happening with the contact, home or other pages.

In this case, adding '/' in  'path('services/', views.services, name='services'),' is working with me. Thanks for this.